# IBM Connections API : Predefined Connections Feed

Tags: ibm-connections

our customer wants a list of the 5 most popular communities of his IBM connections installation. most popular means the communities with the highest amount of entries within the last 2 weeks. I just wonder if we can do this by calling one of the predefined community atom feeds ?
any help would be appreciated

regards marco

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried one of the predefined atom feeds which only returns a list sorted by modification

Comment: @Jonas do you me community forums? what service in Communities are you using to say most amount of entries?

Comment: Have you tried Kudos from ISW? Otherwise just lookup the appropriate tables in the database...

Comment: We have used for example the following feed url https://greenhouse.lotus.com/communities/service/atom/communities/all?sortBy=modified&amp;sortOrder=desc&amp;ps=5 returning 5 community entries sorted by modification date but we are rather interested in a list of communities with the highest amount of created or modified entries within a certain period of time

Comment: @Jonas - do you mean Updates/Activity Stream data or do you mean forum data for a community?